# How to unpack particular list elements into dataframes in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, lapply

Have been researching this question on SO, and found only solutions for merging list elements into one large data frame. However, I am struggling with unpacking only those elements that meet certain condition.

```
df1 <- iris %>% filter(Sepal.Length > 2.5)
df2 <- mtcars %>% filter(qsec > 16)
not_neccessary <- head(diamonds, 10)
not_neccessary2 <- head(beaver1, 12)

data_lists <- list("#123 DATA" = df1, "CON" = not_neccessary2, "#432 DATA" = df2, "COM" = not_neccessary)
```

My goal is to convert only those list elements that contain "DATA" in their name. I was thinking about writing a loop function within a `lapply`:

```
a <- lapply(data_lists, function(x){if (x == "#+[1-9]+_+DATA"){new_df <- as.data.frame(x)}})
```

It does not work. Also was trying to make a `for` loop:

```
for (i in list){
  if (i == "#+[1-9]+_+DATA"){
    df <- i
  }
}
```

It does not work neither.

Is there any effective function that will unpack my list into particular dataframes by certain condition? My R skills are very bad, especially in writing functions, although I am not really new to this language. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grepl`/`grep` to find lists that have 'DATA' in their name and subset the list.

```
result <- data_lists[grepl('DATA', names(data_lists))]
#With `grep`
#result <- data_lists[grep('DATA', names(data_lists))]
```

Comment: Why do we specify ```names()```?

Comment: Because your condition to filter data is based on names of the list and not actual data itself. `df1` does not have any value related to 'DATA' in it. The information is present only in names of `data_lists`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `%like%`

```
result <- data_lists[names(data_lists) %like% 'DATA']
```